# SQL Server container is not reachable to application container

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker-compose to create two containers. One is for Microsoft SQL Server and the other one is for WebApp.

The WebApp container is exiting with exit code 139.

SQL container is running and my required schema is also available I checked by connecting through SSMS but when my application is trying to access the database I am getting an unhandled exception saying:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```yaml
    version: "3.4"
    services:
      sqldb:
        restart: always
        user: root
        container_name: sqldb
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        ports:
          - 1433:1433
        volumes:
          - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql/data
        environment:
          SA_PASSWORD: "testpass"
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      webapi:
        image: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}WebApi"
        ports:
          - 80:80
        environment:
          - Database=Server=sqldb,1433;Database=Emp;User Id=sa;Password=testpass;
        depends_on:
          - sqldb
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: webapi/Source/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      sqlvolume:
        driver: local
```

How to connect SQL server container with application container.

Comment: Is `testpass` the actual password you're trying to apply to the `sa` account? If so then your SQL container probably isn't starting up because `testpass` doesn't meet the password complexity requirements of the [Password Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy).

Comment: Aside... why have you specified `user: root`? The SQL Server service is configured to run with the `mssql` user account.